# ADAL Cordova in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, plugins, visual-studio-cordova, adal

I've been trying to add the new ADAL plugin for Apache Cordova in a Blank Cordova app in Visual studio. I go to config and add plugin. (See picture)
[image]

But it says that it cant download the plugin. I also noticed that the folder structure of the project in Visual Studio when you create a blank app is different from when you create a new app in the console with the CLI.

I would love to use visual studio and Cordova to play with this. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Git is installed in your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I had to download from GIT first, and then install the plugin from "Local", not "Git". For some reason, unkown to me, this worked.